# Is it safe to assign pointer from multiple threads in below situation?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a struct Node. Inside is a pointer to next Node (Node *next).

My graph is such that every next pointer can only point to one node and the same node that is already present in the graph.

In my example multiple threads can operate on nodes. Consider below example, while knowing that nodes a and b are safely added before to the graph.

Code example:

```
Node* a = new Node;
Node* b = new Node;

// from now on multiple threads at the same time

a->next = b;
```

Can a->next be invalid considering that pointer assignment is not atomic?

Edit 1:
I am checking next pointers after all threads stop running.

Comment: no, just like `int`

Comment: @appleapple Are you answering "is it safe" or "can it be invalid"?

Comment: If you're modifying `a->next` concurrently, the entire program is invalid. Reasoning about the value of `a->next`
 afterwards is pointless.

Comment: @molbdnilo just like `int` :D

Comment: since OP seems to think there exist something to make pointer assignment different if the pointee exist. (now I think that it's doesn't make much sense if the pointee not exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsynchronized concurrent writes to the same non-atomic variable cause undefined behavior.

[`[intro.races]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.races-2):

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location ([intro.memory]) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.

[`[intro.races]/21`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.races-21)

> ... The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other ...
>
> Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

Your specific scenario sounds like it might work in practice, but I wouldn't do it, unless you already tried atomics and benchmarking shows them to cause performance problems.

If you're going to use atomics, you can try writing to them using `std::memory_order_relaxed`. From your description, it looks like it would be safe.

Comment: I think I will do that just to be safe. I wanted to be smart about it.

Comment: @dandon223 The "smart" thing here is `relaxed` atomics. :)

Comment: Ok. I benchmarked std::memory_order_relaxed and it is difference is insignificant. Once more thank you.

Comment: hi @ "Unsynchronized concurrent writes to the same non-atomic variable cause undefined behavior - Is a non-atomic variable for example a scalar value such as a number and an atomic variable an array?

Comment: @Daniel A scalar is not atomic. Neither is an array of scalars. An atomic would have the word `atomic` in the type name, e.g. `std::atomic_int x;` (or `std::atomic<int> x;`). An array of atomics is not itself atomic, only the separate elements are.

Comment: "An array of atomics is not itself atomic, only the separate elements are" - @HolyBlackCat only if those elements carry the word `atomic`, right?

Comment: @Daniel Yep....

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking a->next after all threads have finished the assignment. It will be valid.

Comment: I think so too. Yes, I am checking next pointers after all assignments to traverse graph. That is why I do not want to use std::atomic since they are more costly.

Comment: This is not true. Assignment of a non-atomic object from two different threads without synchronisation is undefined. No checking afterwards can change that.